# Can C# Delegates work this way?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to use delegates to cut down on my code in this project.
I have 4 DropDownLists in my asp.net page. In my codebehind file I'm binding them to different business object calls with data. Right now I have the following code:

```
DeptList.DataSource = bl.getAcademicDepts();
DeptList.DataBind();
TermList.DataSource = bl.getTerms();
TermList.DataBind();
InstructorList.DataSource = bl.getInstructors();
InstructorList.DataBind();
EEList.DataSource = bl.getEE();
EEList.DataBind();
```

This seems really repetitive so I decided to make a function as a shortcut

```
private void SourceAndBind(DropDownList d, <business layer method call>)
{
    d.DataSource = <businesslayer method call>();
    d.DataBind();
}
```

Then my first block of code simply becomes

```
SourceAndBind(DeptList, bl.getAcademicDepts());
SourceAndBind(TermList, bl.getTerms());
SourceAndBind(InstructorList, bl.getInstructors());
SourceAndBind(EEList, bl.getEE());
```

However, I don't know what to put for the second parameter. Each one of the business layer calls takes no parameters, but they each return objects of different types. I tried using delegates but I couldn't figure out how to create one without a defined return type or no parameters. Is it possible to achieve what I want with c#? I know that works in python which is where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need delegates to do this. Just declare the second parameter as `object`.

```
// Takes drop down list and data to assign to 'data source'
private void SourceAndBind(DropDownList d, object data) {
    d.DataSource = data;
    d.DataBind();
}

// Call methods from bussiness layer and bind results
SourceAndBind(DeptList, bl.getAcademicDepts());
SourceAndBind(TermList, bl.getTerms());
SourceAndBind(InstructorList, bl.getInstructors());
SourceAndBind(EEList, bl.getEE());
```

You could use delegates too. However, since you're only calling the method once, you can call the bussiness layer method to get the data and then pass the result to `SourceAndBind`. (Delegates would be useful for example if you wanted to choose one of several ways of loading the data, or if you wanted to delay loading until some later point).

Answer (score 3):

Well, `Func<object>` would be a very general way of doing that. That's "a function with no parameters that returns an object". Any parameterless function returning a reference type should be convertible to that delegate type. However, your "usage" code wouldn't be quite right as it. It would be:

```
SourceAndBind(DeptList, bl.getAcademicDepts);
SourceAndBind(TermList, bl.getTerms);
SourceAndBind(InstructorList, bl.getInstructors);
SourceAndBind(EEList, bl.getEE);
```

Note the lack of brackets, which means these are method *groups* rather than method *calls*. (To follow .NET naming conventions I'd suggest renaming your methods to start with capital letters, btw.)

That's appropriate if you only want to *call* the method conditionally. As Tomas says though, you don't need to use delegates here. If you're happy for `SourceAndBind` to only get called *after* you've called the method, you can definitely just perform the method call in the argument and pass the result as `object`.

Comment: ok I didn't put the brackets in literally. I'm just in the habit of using them when I'm making a placeholder in code.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'CourseFinder2.CF1.SourceAndBind(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList, System.Func<object>)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: my method signature is now `private void SourceAndBind(DropDownList d, Func<object> method)` and the above error is what I'm getting ??

Comment: The naming conventions is my python and java coming through. I'll be sure to fix that too ;)

Comment: Well I ended up going with Tomas' method and set it to object. That worked just fine. But when I had the signature as it was in my above comment my calling code was identical to what you have in your answer. No angle brackets. And I had the error about invalid arguments.

Comment: @Matt: Did it give any more details? Usually the compiler error gives what it was *trying* to convert from.

Comment: Ok, so for all 4 of the above DropDownLists, when I use Func<object> method, it complains that it cannot cast from the return type of the business layer functions http://csharp.pastebin.com/Gcu0SdHu

Comment: @Matt: It looks like you've probably still got the brackets on the method calls, rather than converting from method groups. If you could paste in a short but *complete* example, that would be great.

Comment: Ok, you were saying brackets and i was seeing parenthesis! I took them out and now it works. Thanks for the little lesson though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SourceAndBind(DropDownList d, Func<IEnumerable<object>> businessLayerMethod)
{
    d.DataSource = businessLayerMethod();
    d.DataBind();
}
```

`IEnumerable<object>` where object is your datatype.

Comment: This will not work for me because not all of my methods are returning IEnumerable. Some are lists and some are strings too.